# Adding react from separate js file does not work

Tags: reactjs

I was following the 'Add React to a Website' guide on https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx but it does not seem to work correctly for some reason.

The code that does not work:

index.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <!-- Load React -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load React component. -->
    <script src="test.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

test.js:

```
    ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

The code above will produce a blank page but when I add the react code on the index.html page like this:

```
   <script>
    ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
   </script>
```

It does work.

I have tried to replace

```
    <script src="test.js"></script>
```

with

```
    <script src="/test.js"></script>
```

and

```
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
```

but that still does not work.

Also when I inspect element on the blank page it does show that it loads test.js

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Quick fix: move `<script src="test.js"></script>` to below `<div id="root"></div>`. Let me know if you want a full answer.

Comment: It still does not work I have done as you told me.

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening. Basically, follow the guide you linked to more carefully. You need `<script src="test.js" type="text/babel"></script>`.

Comment: Aha ok thank you it works now!

Comment: I've written an answer so that an answer can be accepted for this question. For what it's worth, I recommend [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) if you want to get started with React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx) says:

> Now you can use JSX in any `<script>` tag by adding `type="text/babel"`
>   attribute to it.

So you need `<script src="test.js" type="text/babel"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Even you can do it without adding text/babel by just using React.creatElement API as recommneded by **Dan Abramov**, *author of redux and part of Reactjs core team*.

Here is the working codesanbox: [React with no build config](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jrk6l3qx)

Comment: Sure, it works without JSX. But nobody wants to write React without JSX...

Comment: Yeah this is for just understanding